# What is the difference between a directory between slashes, after a slash, and ending with a slash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

What is the difference between a directory name listed between slashes, after a slash, and ending with a slash?

For example, `/bin/`, `/bin`, and `bin/`

Comment: Related: [Absolute / canonical / relative paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398412/absolute-canonical-relative-paths)

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/` is an absolute path to the 'bin' directory.

`/bin` is an absolute path to the 'bin' file (that may be a directory)

`bin/` is a relitive path to the 'bin' directory.

For completeness:

`bin` is a relative path to the 'bin' file (that may be a directory)

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical difference between `/bin/` and `/bin`, except `/bin/` is more explicit in communicating that it is a directory. A naive program may look for that as a clue to decide if it looks like a file or directory.

The last one, though, will refer to a `bin` directory in the current working directory. If you are in the root directory, `/`, it will coincide with the previous two references. Whenever you change directories, the directory that is referenced will change, if it exists at all.

Comment: The trailing `/` is more than a clue. In a bash pattern it will only match directories, and many of the core utilities (stat, ls, grep...) will complain if an argument with a trailing `/` is not a directory. And in some applications it is important, for instance `rsync` will omit a level of directory nesting when copying directories if the source has a trailing `/`.

Comment: POSIX *requires* that a path ending in `/` be treated as a directory, and there is nothing naive about that.

Comment: `cp file /somedir` will either make a copy of a file called `/somedir` if it isn't a directory or `/somedir/file` if it is.  I don't know how many times I've had to delete files created that way.  `cp file /somedir/` will throw an error if `/somedir/` doesn't exist.  Things are just easier when you are in the habit of using a trailing `/`.

Comment: If I recall right FreeBSD and macOS even require the trailing slash if you wanted to copy a directory *into* a target directory. Without that slash it was replacing the target directory with the newly copied one. So, this one character may have a devastating difference under some circumstances. On Linux `cp dir /some_other_dir` is smartly handled and “virtually” (it will not appear on screen) adds the BSD-slash to still copy the source into the destination.  Habitually I’m adding it when copying into and leave it away when acting directly on it.